# Reuse a rendered layout in some other layout at run time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using a *RecylerView* inside a layout *l1.xml*. I am including this *l1.xml* inside *l2.xml* using include tag.
I update this RecyclerView after an api call but l2.xml is not showing the updated RecyclerView.

Is there a way to forcibly ask the parent to refresh?

invalidate(), refreshDrawableState(); on the parent layout didn't help?

Is there a smarter way to use a rendered layout in multiple places?

*l1.xml*

```
...
...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/feed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="@color/light_primary_background">

    <include layout="@layout/events_list"/>
</LinearLayout>
...
...
```

events_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/events_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I update the *events_recycler_view* after an API call and the events_list.xml is updated but the include in l1.xml is not updated

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far..!!

Comment: How do you update your RecyclerView?

Comment: What do you mean by "events_list.xml is updated but the include in l1.xml is not updated"? Is events_list.xml visible independently?

Comment: I update recyclerview from an api call.  My intent is to use events_list.xml at 2 places

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can always use LayoutInflater to inflate a view, but the view must have the ids and type matching the id and type defined in your java code.

Check out this link for how to use layout inflater

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.view.LayoutInflater